# Cannot test my web service on Browser

Tags: java, web-services

I followed a very simple like and created a web service using Netbeans http://martcode.com/tipsGallery/Making-SOAP-Webservice-With-Netbeans.php?id=39

Glassfish server is running fine and properly project is deployed. However in the last step of this tutorial, when I right click on my Web service and click "Test Web Service", I cannot test it using The browser. I have already added ?Tester at the end of link but nothing happens.

I see the following output:

Web Services
Endpoint    Information

```
Service Name:   // AL text
Port Name:      // All text

Address:    // the addres //
WSDL:   http:zokalhozt(speling changed due to restirictions here):8284/MyOperation/MyOperationWS?wsdl
Implementation class:   add.CMyOperationWS
```

Now I can see the WSDL and can test it using SOAP UI but why can't I test it using the browser itself? Please note I added ?Tester at the end but nothing happens. I always get the same output.

Comment: check java brains webservice tutorial from youtube it might be helpful [link](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=java+brains+web+services&oq=java+br&gs_l=youtube.3.2.0l10.378.1881.0.7060.4.3.1.0.0.0.463.754.1j0j1j0j1.3.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.yaP1Kb6RLfE)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken SOAP web services get their parameters with HTTP POST and not by URL parameters. This is why it can't simply be called in the browser.

Comment: use advanced rest client with chrome. you can invoke post requests